# Firefox Background Image Weirdness

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

Firefox isn't interpreting my background header image the way IE, Chrome, or Safari do. Why is that?

Page: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms/page.php
How it should look: http://cl.ly/OCbp

HTML:

```
<header class="banner banner-1">
   <h1>About Us</h1>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
.banner {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
height: 229px;
padding-top:105px;
z-index: 0;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #8ab2a9;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: bottom; 
}

.banner-1 {
background-image: url(../images/banners/banner-01.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
.banner-1 { background-position: center bottom;}
```

And it should work.

Comment: It works! How come those rules don't transfer and apply from the "banner" class?

Comment: @pianofighter I was wondering about the same thing. When looking at Chrome's dev tools, I can see you added the `background-position` property, but it is not there in Firefox. Very strange!

Comment: Another notch on the post of compatibility mysteries. Thank you for the fix!

Comment: !!! New to StackOverflow - didn't even see that the checkmark was available to me

Comment: background-position-x/y aren't supported in a lot of browsers. It's better to specify them as background-position: x y